# How to add multilanguage Refinery CMS control panel?

Tags: refinerycms

There is a "Change language" button at the bottom-right of the [refinery demo site](http://demo.refinerycms.com/refinery)'s control panel.

[image]

But the button doesn't show up when I setup my own site. I try to copy some settings in demo site like "I18n Translation Enabled", still lack of luck. Can't find any document on the refinery site or google.

Comment: Do you have the `gem 'refinerycms-i18n',         '~> 1.0.0'` gem installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this add the gem to Gemfile

It should be there by default, but just double check in case.

```
gem 'refinerycms-i18n'
```

Run the generator

```
rails g refinerycms_i18n
```

Change the language settings

In Refinery's settings find I18n Translation Frontend Locales (Refinery) and add the ISO country name.

```
--- 
- :en
- :ru
- :de
```

That's it! Visit the Pages tab and you should see flags indicating the page language in the tree.
[image: ImageOne]

Edit a page and you'll see the available languages at the top. Simply select one to add content for that language.

[image: ImageTwo]

Comment: here is the new command to run the generator,
# rails g refinery:i18n

Comment: @Whassup : Thanks for the comment. Let me check and get back to you.